# Combining Two Functions to Execute

Tags: python

I am trying to use asciimatics and winsound.Beep to create a visual that plays beeping sound together.I have two functions that needs to be executed at the same time so that beeping sound comes out when my asciimatics visual start to play. Please help.

Comment: Please go through this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To have two things run "at the same time", you'd use either multi-processing or multi-threading. We'll likely need far more context to be able to make any more complete suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from threading import Thread

def f():
    print("f")

def g():
    print("g")

def f_and_g_at_once():
    t1 = Thread(target=f)
    t2 = Thread(target=g)
    t1.start() # returns immediately after the thread starts
    t2.start()

f_and_g_at_once()
```

or

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    print("f")

def g():
    print("g")

def f_and_g_at_once():
    p1 = Process(target=f)
    p2 = Process(target=g)
    p1.start() # returns immediately after the process starts
    p2.start()

# This condition is important, see:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f_and_g_at_once()
```

What is better depends on the context but in your case the `threading` variant would be better choice.